# Redirecting parked domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

actually I own three domains lets say a.com , b.com and c.com
I bought a hosting for a.com and then the others were parked
This is my actual htacess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.b\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http:// www..com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^c\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.c\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.c\.com\/history\/" [R=301,L]
```

How could I redirect c.com exclusively to a subfolder like "history" without having the url changed in the browser

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?c\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /history/ [L]
```

So basically just remove `http://` part from target of the rule.